# mixed effects modelling of unbalanced repeated measures data

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, unbalanced-classes

I have radio tracking data on 34 animals over a period of up to 26 months. For about 6 animals I have all the data, for 2 others I only have a couple of months, and the rest lie somewhere in between. We are looking to do a seasonal analysis of home range with males and females, only animals which have a minimum number of 50 fixes in a season are included. Due to my issue with repeated measures on an individual (some animals have 3 summers of data) and lack of data for others (some animals only have winter, for example), I am wondering on the best way to approach the analysis of this data set. GLMM did not work due to missing observations. I am interested in the differences in size of home range between seasons, between males and females, and for the same season across years. I was using animal as the random effect and year, season and male/female are all fixed and are factors. Home range is continuous and non-normally distributed according to shapiro test. I am using R.

Comment: What did you use when you tried GLMM? Missing observations are not a problem for GLMM in general, but may be problematic for particular software implementation.

Comment: We used the lme4 package in R, with a few variations of the following code: glmm5=glmer(CoreHR~MF*Season+(1|Year/Animal), family=Gamma, data=SeasonalHR). We also tried using both Poisson and Gaussian, and with Year as a fixed effect and Animal as the random. None of the outputs made any sense, so we have fallen back on a log linear model at this stage. Thanks.

Comment: The ultimate problem may not be missing data (empty cells) per se, but rather the total amount of data available. Both GLM and LMM models require more data than LM to estimate as there are more parameters, and GLMM is thus doubly bad.

Comment: Also, it is somewhat unusual to use Year as a grouping variable in your random effects -- unless you have a lot of years (you need several levels to estimate variance components) and you don't care about the ordinal structure of year (i.e. you don't view Year as representing time-series information). As such, Year may better belong in the fixed effects, which will also make your model easier to estimate.

Comment: Thanks Livius, I think you are correct on both accounts. We ended up putting Year in as a fixed effect rather than the random component (we only had 3 levels) and used a log-LME model, which seems to work well with the data. Thanks for your comments.